# Can I turn cryptocurrency into giftcards without being taxed?

Tags: cryptocurrency

Alright, so my idea is to trade crypto then turn it into giftcards since I don't have a bank account. I want to make sure taxes don't apple. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

This does not work. When the transfer your crypto in exchange for something else that is a taxable disposition of the crypto and any appreciation in value it has experienced is subject to capital gains taxation.

If you don't self-report it, you are committing tax fraud, for which there are significant civil penalties and potentially even criminal penalties.